# Invalid selector error on setting delegate: Xcode 10 swift 4

Tags: ios, uitextfield, swift4, xcode10

The app crashes on the line where I set the TextField delegate:

```
listNameTextField = self
```

in the `viewDidLoad` method

Gives error

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I have already tried to make the `listNameTextField` variable `strong` over `weak` reference but it does not change the problem

```
import UIKit

class CreateListViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var listNameTextField: UITextField!
    var listNameString: String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = "Create List"
        listNameTextField.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func submitListName(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if listNameString != "" {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ListView")
            self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        if let text = listNameTextField.text {
            listNameString = text
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your error, your `listNameTextField` is just `UIView`.
Check connections in your `xib`/`storyboard`.

You can't change type of `UIView` in storyboard to `UITextField`, since storyboard generate additional properties in xml for `UITextField`.

Instead you need to delete your original `UIView` from storyboard and add new `UITextField` and make new connection.

Comment: The storyboard shows an outlet `listNameTextField ---- List Name Text Field`.        I think that means it is the correct type. I made sure to change the `UIView` to `UITextField` when making the connection.

Comment: Thanks, actually you were right, it worked when I re-added it.

Comment: @PranayPant happy to help. Don't forget to mark as answer :)